# Web Service Data Stage

Tags: web-services, datastage, infosphere-spl

I get the following error:Service Invocation Exeption i am working with Version 8.7 IBM InfoSphere DataStage and QualityStage Designer and using a server job and there, i have 1 sequential file, web service, sequential file.

Any idea what could be the reason of this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have chosen proper DataStage job type and your stage that operates on web service is configured properly.
You should also check the DataStage logs to get more information about root cause of the error.